# Swift Charts' chartXVisibleDomain hangs or crashes

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-charts

If I use the following *Swift Charts* `Chart` anywhere (Xcode Simulator, Playground, etc.) it hangs or crashes. As soon as I remove the `chartXVisibleDomain` modifier everything works. Is anybody else experiencing the same issue and/or knows how to fix it? I'm on Xcode Version 15.0 (15A240d).

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let data: [(day: Date, value: Int)] = [
        (Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 0,   to: .now)!, 1),
        (Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1,  to: .now)!, 2),
        (Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -3,  to: .now)!, 3),
        (Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -10, to: .now)!, 4),
        (Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -20, to: .now)!, 5)
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        Chart(data, id: \.day) { (day, value) in
            BarMark(
                x: .value("Date", day, unit: .day),
                y: .value("Value", value)
            )
        }
        .chartXVisibleDomain(length: 2)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By trial and error, I found that the number passed to `chartXVisibleDomain` in this case should be in *seconds*. This kind of makes sense, since `Date` is kind of like a wrapper around `timeIntervalSince1970`, which is in seconds.

The app hangs probably because you are drawing a *really really* wide chart - you are saying you only want to see 2 seconds at a time, of the whole 20-day data.

You can do:

```
.chartXVisibleDomain(length: 86400*2) // 86400 seconds in 24 hours
```

instead.